# How do I access an external webcam with OpenCV?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv

The big problem lies in the fact that the code, no matter which number I type in to VideoCapture cap(), it will always find the internal webcap of my laptop - Or die trying.
I have tried going in to devices and deactivated the internal one, but
it did little good.
(By the way, I'm new at this forum, so be gentle.)

Here's the code ( Not including the Rotation function.)

```
int main()
{   
    // NOW WITH WEBCAM INPUT!!
    VideoCapture cap(0);//capture image from webcam
    cap.open(true); 
    Mat image;
    cap>>image; //applying the captured image to Mat image
    //Mat image = imread("Tulips.jpg"); // reading the image
    double degrees; // Number of degrees we want to rotate the image
    double oregoX = image.cols / 2; //X-center of the image
    double oregoY = image.rows / 2; //Y-center of the image

    //user inputs
    cout << "please enter the number of degrees you wish to turn the image" << endl;
    cin >> degrees;

    cout << "\n\nplease enter at which point (X, Y) you want to rotate the image\n(make space not comma)\n" << endl;
    cout << "The center of the image is at " << oregoX << ", " << oregoY << endl;
    cin >> oregoX >> oregoY;

    while (true){
        cap>>image;

        if (!image.data) break;
        if (waitKey(30) >= 0) break;

        cvtColor(image, image, CV_8U); //Converting image to 8-bit
        Mat grayImage; //creating a canvas for the grayscale image
        cvtColor(image, grayImage, CV_RGB2GRAY); //creating the grayscale image

        // Here we create a canvas with the same size as the input image, later to put in the rotated data
        Mat imageOut(grayImage.rows, grayImage.cols, CV_8U);

        Rotation(grayImage, imageOut, degrees, oregoX, oregoY); //Performing the rotation on the image using the Rotation() funcion

        imshow("The Gray Image", grayImage);
        imshow("The rotated image", imageOut);

    }
}
```

Comment: what OS are you using? I suspect it may be an OS issue

Comment: Would you mind setting up a very simple example with the `C`-interface instead of `C++` and using `cvCaptureFromCAM(int device)` instead of the `VideoCapture`-class?

Comment: To avoid further troubleshooting, I retried disabeling the internal webcam - And it suddenly works. I am using Windows 7.
So to conclude: 
Device manager -> Locate internal webcam -> Disable internal webcam.
Sorry to have wasted your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Device manager -> Locate internal webcam -> Disable internal webcam.
The default webcam will then become whichever webcam that you plug in 
afterwards.

Answer (score -2):

```
VideoCapture cap(1); //capture image from other webcam
```