# Why am I encountering !_src.empty() error with cv2?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I keep on encountering the error:

```
[ WARN:0] global C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-wvn_it83\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_msmf.cpp (434) `anonymous-namespace'::SourceReaderCB::~SourceReaderCB terminating async callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Home\PycharmProjects\handtracking\HandTrackingModule.py", line 60, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Home\PycharmProjects\handtracking\HandTrackingModule.py", line 47, in main
    img = detector.findHands(img)
  File "C:\Users\Home\PycharmProjects\handtracking\HandTrackingModule.py", line 19, in findHands
    imgRGB = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.1) C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-wvn_it83\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:182: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'
```

Whenever I try to run the code below and I am not sure why. Can someone help me?

```
import cv2
import mediapipe as mp
import time


class handDetector():
    def __init__(self, mode=False, maxHands=2, detectionCon=0.5, trackCon=0.5):
        self.mode = mode
        self.maxHands = maxHands
        self.detectionCon = detectionCon
        self.trackCon = trackCon

        self.mpHands = mp.solutions.hands
        self.hands = self.mpHands.Hands(self.mode, self.maxHands, self.detectionCon, self.trackCon)  
        self.mpDraw = mp.solutions.drawing_utils


    def findHands(self, img, draw=True):
        imgRGB = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        results = self.hands.process(imgRGB) 
        

        if results.multi_hand_landmarks:
            for handLms in results.multi_hand_landmarks:
                if draw:
                    self.mpDraw.draw_landmarks(img, handLms, self.mpHands.HAND_CONNECTIONS)
        return img


def main():
    pTime = 0
    cTime = 0
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
    detector = handDetector()
    while True:
        success, img = cap.read()
        img = detector.findHands(img)

        cTime = time.time()
        fps = 1 / (cTime - pTime)
        pTime = cTime

        cv2.putText(img, str(int(fps)), (10, 70), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SCRIPT_SIMPLEX, 1, (255, 0, 255), 3)

        cv2.imshow("Image", img)
        cv2.waitKey(1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: The error says `cv::cvtColor` do not accept empty image as input. You should check the result of `cap.read()`.

Comment: try cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0) if you only have one camera, it's typically device nr 0

Answer (score 0):

It means that the `img` returned from `success, img = cap.read()` is `None`, also meaning that the `success` returned is `False`.

If you have a webcam built into your pc, than you can try `cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)`. If not, you can try passing into the brackets the path of a video file, like

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture("C:/Users/Username/Desktop/video.mp4")
```

Finally, if it's an external webcam/camera you're trying to access, you can have a look at [How do I access an external webcam with OpenCV?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8136261/13552470).

Answer (score 0):

If you have a built-in webcam into your pc then you can try
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0).
If not, you can try by replacing 0 by 1
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)